# State is not being updated. When I log the data it shows "value below evaluated just now"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to update the state with the data fetched from the API call which is an array of objects. But whenever I try to update the state, the state is not being updated. When I log the value I only get the array representation but when I expand it, It shows me length 0 and that the value below evaluated just now.

[image: console window]

I have tried to return an array from the function and then setState but it didn't change anything, the error still persisted.

The function which fetches data from the server which is in a different file

```
fetchCollege = async (page)=>{
      let url = `${apiUrl}/fetchcollege`

    try {
      let body = {
        noOfPostsToSkip:page*5
      }
      body = JSON.stringify(body)
      let response = await fetch(url,{
        method:"POST",
        body,
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      return await response.json()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error(error)
    }

  }
```

The part where I am updating the state and logging the updated state

```
fetchColleges=async ()=>{
    const { page } = this.state
    try {
      let data = await fetchCollege(page)
      console.log(data)
      // if user is on the first page the data will be same but after that 
      // paginate the newly fetched data by adding data to the pre-existing
      // data array
      let dataArr = page == 0 ? data : [...this.state.data,data]
      this.dataHolder = dataArr
      await this.setState({
        isLoading:false,
        data,
        isRefreshing:false,
      },()=>console.log(this.state))  

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      this.setState({
        isLoading:false,
        isRefreshing:false
      },()=>{
        Alert.alert("Technical Error","A technical error has occured please contact the technical team")
      })

    }
  }
```

I would like to update the state with the fetched data. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Couldn't find any issue with the code. Probably the API returning an empty array. Have a look at the repl link. 
https://repl.it/repls/VigorousWellgroomedDemos

Comment: No. I got a suggestion from another answer to try console.log(Json.stringify(data)) and I saw the data being returned. I too can't find any error in this code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second async function at all. In your first function that makes the call...

````
      const response = await fetch(url,{
        method:"POST",
        body,
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      const result = response.json();
      this.setState({somefield: response})
    ```
````

Comment: Actually the function fetchCollege is in a different file. I have separated my Services with the Components